# Edit List Item when Edit is clicked and Save in Context Menu in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, contextmenu

I am using Android v4. I have created  a list View which displays person contacts

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  public ListView mainListView ;
  public ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Find the ListView resource. 
    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById( R.id.mainListView );
    String[] contacts = new String[] { "Adam", "James", "Alex", "Tom",
                                      "Horton", "Jim","Einstein","Thomson","Dick","Mascow"};  
    ArrayList<String> contactsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    contactsList.addAll( Arrays.asList(contacts) );

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.rowview, contactsList);
    listAdapter.add( "Cameroon" );

    // Set the ArrayAdapter as the ListView's adapter.
    mainListView.setAdapter( listAdapter ); 
    registerForContextMenu(mainListView);  
}
```

which displays ContextMenu on long Click on List Item.
  And the Context_menu.xml is as follows,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item 
   android:id="@+id/Edit"
   android:title="@string/Edit">
 </item> 

 <item
   android:id="@+id/Delete"
   android:title="@string/Delete">     
 </item> 

</menu>
```

When "Delete" in Context Menu is clicked I am getting the ListItem Value removing the ListItem from List. And my code for Context Menu is as follows,

```
   public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info=(AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.Edit: 
        // Edit List Item and Save
        return true;
    case R.id.Delete:
        listAdapter.remove(listAdapter.getItem(info.position));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return true;        
}
```

Now, my doubt is how to edit particular List Item when Edit button is clicked and Save     the Edited Contact.

I am new to Android and doesn't have any idea about handling events.
Please anyone help!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do do like this

```
View view = yourListView.getChildAt(index - 
   yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
TextView someText = ((TextView) view findViewById(R.id.textview01));
someText.setText("updated");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to take the Input from User dynamically and save.